# Signalr backpane scaleout

Tags: signalr

I am using a DB  Named  : MyServiceDB  for signalR scaleout for my application.

Another application that is also doing SignalR stuff wants to use my DB for Scaleout.

Will there be any performance loss or delay with different applications sharing a DB for Scaleout?

Should each app use its own DB for Scaleout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the same database to scale out separate SignalR applications. Each application will try to initialize database and may drop tables the other application created. SignalR also assumes that there is a global, monotonically increasing cursor pointing to the last message. I don't think you are able to guarantee this with two separate applications. I also think you may get weird issues like getting messages meant for one application to be sent to another, missing messages or seeing the same message multiple times etc.

Comment: Thanks is there any documentation in Signalr about two applications sharing the same DB ?